# JavaScript DateTimePicker returns wrong unix time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, datetimepicker, unix-timestamp

I am using the DateTimePicker JavaScript library from http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/. I really like its GUI and basically it works really fine. But then I tested something like this:

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker_unixtime').datetimepicker({
  format:'unixtime'
});
```

The text input field with `id="datetimepicker_unixtime"` should contain the selected time as unix-time in seconds. But when I selected the `1st of January 1970 at 00:00` the displayed unix-time in the text field was near to `-3600` and when I selected `01:00` on the same date it was about `0`. But these values always varied a little bit around those numbers. It was all tested on the demo site from the link above.

My question is, why is the unix time about one hour too early and why does it vary? Is that a mistake of JavaScript or the DateTimePicker library?

Comment: Sounds like a time zone or daylight saving issue.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Good point! That probably explains that it is an hour earlier. But why is it not exactly an hour earlier? It varies by around +- 50 seconds

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your timezone, the following snippet returns different results, depending on the client time zone for example: 1.1.1970 01:00:00 GMT+1:00 - in mine (CET)

```js
    function tm(unix_tm) {
        var dt = new Date(unix_tm*1000);
        document.writeln(dt.getHours() + '/' + dt.getMinutes() + '/' + dt.getSeconds() + ' -- ' + dt + '<br>');

    }

tm(0);
```

Comment: But it still varies by around plus minus 50 seconds around the time zone difference

Comment: That would be quite a bit digging into the 1.500 lines of the plugin code, start a bounty. My first guess - something happens on load or when you first focus, because I'll get the same (but truly strange) results until I reload the page, then deviation is different.